# Website not displaying correctly on mobile devices

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, viewport

I cannot seem to figure out why certain pages on my website are not displaying correctly on mobile devices. Here is a link to the type of page I'm having trouble with: http://www.designelopers.com/html-2/what-is-html/

If you view it in chrome and inspect it in chromes mobile viewer (little mobile icon to the left of inspection toolbar) and select say apple's iphone 6 and refresh you can see the issue I'm having. Here is a picture of what it looks like:

[image: site body is squished to left]

Right now I have the main width's for my content set to percentages. If I change them to pixels it works but I don't really want to do that. I added a few media queries for medium and high pixel densities like so:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)  {

{
#sidebarContainer {
display: none;
float: none;
}
#mainContentContainer {
float: none;
border: none;
width: 100%}
#textSectionInner {
padding: 5rem;
}

}

@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  {

{
#sidebarContainer {
display: none;
float: none;
}
#mainContentContainer {
float: none;
border: none;
width: 100%}
#textSectionInner {
padding: 5rem;
}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is occuring? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

You need to create media queries for different screen sizes. The most common is a desktop version, medium(for tablets), small (for phones). Search media queries.

Comment: Ya, I added some for high pixel density screens but still no luck.

Comment: I put the ones I used up top

Comment: I'm not positive if this will help, but I have my media queries set up like this. @media screen and (max-width:640px) {   /*-code-*/ }

Comment: Ya I have those as well and they work in a desktop browser window. It's just mobile devices things aren't coming together and it's driving me nuts lol

Answer (score 0):

Link-
[Responsive Design](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/)

A little more than halfway down the article has information that I think may help.

link-[Another Helpful Example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_mediaquery)

Hope this helps.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Thank you I shall try those links. And ya I have the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> already in the head of my page.